# Depth First Search for Graph not working right

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

I am trying to do a C# implementation of the Depth First Search. For easy access, I have a `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` to store the vertex and the edges.

The Dict values are :

```
Vertex | Edges List
--------------------
0      | {1}
--------------------
1      |  {2}
--------------------
2      | {0} 
--------------------
```

---

```
static Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

public class Graph
    {
        public int Vertex;
        public List<int> Edges;

        public Graph(int V, List<int> E)
        {
            Vertex = V;
            Edges = E;
            dict.Add(V, E);
        }

public void DFS(Graph g)
{
     Stack<int> stk = new Stack<int>();
     int[] visited = new int[4];

     stk.Push(g.Vertex);
     visited[0] = g.Vertex;
     int i = 1;
     while (stk.Count > 0)
     {
         foreach (var item in dict[stk.Peek()])
         {
             if (!visited.Contains(item))
             {
                 visited[i] = item;
                 stk.Push(item);
                 i++;
             }
         }
         Console.WriteLine(stk.Peek());
         stk.Pop();
    }
}
```

I only get 0 and 1 in my Depth First Search. I understand that there are different ways of doing it, but I believe my approach is also one of the ways and I need help fixing this piece of code.

Comment: What are Vertex and Edges?

Comment: First of all, you should provide an example that compiles and shows how you construct your graph and call your function

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, your code does the following:
 1. push the first Vertex to the Stack
 2. peek at it, and search for the first edge not in the stack
 3. push that to the stack
 4. peek at it
 5. POP it from the stack. With this step, the first Vertex (in this case, it's Vertex 0) gets to the top of the stack, then your code goes to the 2.point.
Since vertex 2 can't be reached from vertex 0 in one step, your algorithm stops.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, that this data model uses directed graphs, not sure if that's intentional.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest to you an existing, simple and useful implementation of Depth First Traversal: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/d45294865625aae1bf972f331a6737961473d136/MoreLinq/Traverse.cs#L87

The interesting part:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TraverseDepthFirst<T>(T root, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector)
{
    if (childrenSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(childrenSelector));

    return _(); IEnumerable<T> _()
    {
        var stack = new Stack<T>();
        stack.Push(root);

        while (stack.Count != 0)
        {
            var current = stack.Pop();
            yield return current;
            // because a stack pops the elements out in LIFO order, we need to push them in reverse
            // if we want to traverse the returned list in the same order as was returned to us
            foreach (var child in childrenSelector(current).Reverse())
                stack.Push(child);
        }
    }
}
```

By mirroring the implementation into your code, we'd get what follows:

```
public void DFS(Graph g)
{
     Stack<int> stk = new Stack<int>();
     HashSet<int> visited = new HashSet<int>();

     stk.Push(g.Vertex);
     visited.Add(g.Vertex);
     while (stk.Count > 0)
     {
         int current = stk.Pop();
         Console.WriteLine(current);
         foreach (var item in dict[current])
         {
             if (visited.Add(item))
             {
                 // Add returns true if the element wasn't in the set already
                 stk.Push(item);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

I've removed `i` variable as we're now using HashSet to track visited vertices, and moved `Console.WriteLine` and `stk.Pop()` to the beginning as that's more closely aligned with what we see in MoreLinq code, also that simplifies the code.

Your method is Depth First *Search*, yet you're only "visiting" all nodes (and I'm guessing that `Console.WriteLine` is a placeholder for the actual "find/visit" operation). In it's current form it's Traversal operation, for Search you'd need to actually compare vertices with something you look for, and return some kind of result.

Comment: While I understand your code, I might have a question regarding the concept behind it. I thought DFS is print vertex,go to one of it's neighbors,print it and then check for one of it's neighbors. However your code looks at all the neighbors of a neighbor instead of one. It looks like your code does BFS instead.

Comment: I've edited your code, and if you find it right approve the edit and I will accept the answer.

Comment: Accept the pending edit to this answer if it seems right, otherwise it will be rejected as it contains changes to code.

Comment: @TheFallenOne I cannot accept your edit. There is a fundamental misunderstanding of algorithms here. Your algorithm doesn't sound like either of DFS or BFS. In DFS (depth-first) visiting given vertex consists of "processing" current and then visiting all of it's neighbors (which creates recurrency, avoided here by usage of the stack), whereas in BFS (breadth-first) visiting given vertex consists of "processing" the vertex and adding all the neighbors at the end of the queue - and the algorithm runs until the queue is empty. Essentially: DFS is visit&stack-children; BFS is visit&queue-children.